# new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"), I would like change color background, button and other

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like change background color, button and other properties of this activity:

```
new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")
```

Where I can find all possible values for putExtra?

Is possible to also change layout of this activity?

Answer (score 2):

> i would like change color background, button and other of this activity

That is not possible in general. Not only do you not have any way of asking for this, but the activity may not have any sort of button, for example.

> where I can find All Possible putextra?

That is [an undocumented `Intent` action](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Any activity implementing it is welcome to ignore all extras or support whatever extras it wants to. Devices do not have to have any activity that supports this undocumented extra.

There are many [image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available for Android. Please use one.